# Node Range Error, Max Callstack Size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been looking at a few other questions here on Stack Overflow in regards to similar problems. Supposedly this issue is due to function recursion, but I'm not 100% sure if this is the same case--as you will see below.

This is the culprit function, where the error is thrown:

```
/* inits AND parses research projects from database */
Game.prototype.initAndParseResearch = function(city, research){
    var research = JSON.parse(research);
    var d = new Date().getTime();

    //object that contains active research projects
    var projects = research.active;

    //loop through each active project and "init" the research
    for(var project in projects){
        var obj = this.GameCfg.research_projects[project];
        var timeUntil = (projects[project].started + (obj.time * 60 * 1000)) - d;

        //minimum 0 - don't want a negative time for setTimeout()
        if(timeUntil < 0){
            timeUntil = 0;
        }

        //start timeout
        var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('YOU FAILED.');
            //this.researchFinished(city, project);
        }.bind(this), 5000);


        city.research = research;
        city.research.active[project] = {
            timeout : timeout
        };
    }
}
```

The error thrown for specifics:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:82
        throw err;
              ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

C:\xampp\htdocs>
```

Now, the culprit seems to be when the function tries to store the handle that is returned from `setTimeout`. Why can't I store the timeout reference? I can **NOT** store it and have everything work smoothly, but then I would not have any reference to the timeout object if I ever need to run `clearTimeout`.

**updated code**

```
/* inits AND parses research projects from database */
Game.prototype.initAndParseResearch = function(Player, city, research){
    var research = JSON.parse(research);
    var d = new Date().getTime();

    //object that contains active research projects
    var projects = research.active;

    //loop through each active project and "init" the research
    for(var project in projects){
        var obj = this.GameCfg.research_projects[project];
        var timeUntil = (projects[project].started + (obj.time * 60 * 1000)) - d;

        //minimum 0 - don't want a negative time for setTimeout()
        if(timeUntil < 0){
            timeUntil = 0;
        }

        city.research = research;

        //start timeout
        var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            this.researchFinished(Player, city, project);
        }.bind(this), timeUntil);

        Player.timeouts['research_'+project] = timeout;
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather the problem is that you cannot call `setTimeout` because that blows the stack. Please show us a stack trace. What function does call `initAndParseResearch`?

Comment: @Bergi Hi, thanks for the response. `initAndParseResearch` is called by a function in my `Player` prototype, which is where the `city` object resides. I seemed to have gotten past the issue by adding an object called `timeouts` to my `Player` "class", and storing the timeout their instead of within the `city` object. Updated my code.